# How to add a delay to a jQuery toggle

Tags: jquery

I am toggling the following classes from hidden to visible on click of .more:

```
$( ".more, .less" ).click(function() {
var $this = $(this);
  $this.siblings(".controls").toggle();
  $this.siblings(".phone").toggle();
  $this.siblings(".less").toggle();
  $this.toggle();
});
```

Question: at the moment, this all occurs instantaneously, how can I set these to occur 2s apart (in the order the are shown)?

Comment: have you tried using .delay()?

Comment: @im_benton no, how would this work? thanks

Answer (score 1):

Add a [.delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) before the [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/), and pass a parameter to .toggle() to set how fast you want the toggle to be. It seems if you don't tell toggle how fast it want's to be, even by default of 400, it will show instantly.

```
$('.box').delay(1000).toggle(400);
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4kLnk/)